# How to get self values in decorators from tasks.py

Tags: python-2.7, python-decorators, django-celery

I need some help to get values from a class inside a decorator, I keep getting stuck.

**tasks.py**

```
@lazy_task()
def import_(date_time):
  importer = Importer(date_time=date_time)
  importer.import_jira()
```

**import_.py**

```
class Importer(object):

   RECIPIENTS = 'friday@gmail.com'  

   def __init__(self, date_time=None):
     self.date_time = data_time

   def import_jira(self):
     pass
```

**decorators.py**

```
def lazy_task():

  def decorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def get_lazy_task(self, *args, **kwargs):            
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print self.RECIPIENTS  # Not working            
    return get_lazy_task

  return decorator
```

Please help me how to get `RECIPIENTS` in `decorator` from the file `import.py`

Comment: Try posting the contents of the entire files for better understanding.

Comment: And don't use keywords for function names or filenames. `import` is a keyword in python.

Answer (score 1):

In the file `import_.py`, `RECIPIENTS` is a `static variable` of the class `Importer`. This means, the variable `RECIPIENTS` needs to be accessed by `<class-name>.<var-name>`, which is this case is `Importer.RECIPIENTS`.

I would suggest you import `Importer` from `import_.py` and print `Importer.RECIPIENTS` instead of `self.RECIPIENTS`.

Add this line to the file `decorators.py`

```
from import_ import Importer
```

and change the print statement from `print self.RECIPIENTS` to

```
print Importer.RECIPIENTS
```

I wrote a simple example to make this work.

**foo.py**

```
class Foo:
    VALUE = 'value'

    def __init__():
        pass
```

**bar.py**

```
from functools import wraps
from foo import Foo  # importing class Foo from foo.py

def bar():
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def inner():
            print Foo.VALUE
        return inner
    return decorator

bar()(lambda: None)()
```

On running the file `bar.py` we get this output.

```
$ python bar.py
value
```

If you don't want to add an extra line of import statement at the top of every file that needs to use the `RECIPIENTS` value, you can directly import and print like this

```
print __import__('import_').Importer.RECIPIENTS
```

However, there is no other way of accessing a value from another file without importing it.

Answer (score -1):

In your `import_` function, the `Importer` instance is a local variable - not a function's argument -, so it can NOT be accessed by the decorator. Period.